# Python Session request is parsing the data argument wrongly

Tags: python, json, parsing, session, request

I'm trying to send a request to a server and also a json as data argument. If I use straight request, it works, but when I use session I get a bad request as result.

THIS WORKS:

```
import request

url = "https://whatever/api/v1/dosomething"
data = {"client":{"id":100},"job":{"name":"software developer","field_id":[1,2,3],"level":20}}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

When I check r.request.body, I get the following:

```
'{"client": {"id": 100}, "job": {"name": "software developer", "field_id": [1, 2, 3], "level": 20}}'
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

When I try to use Session though, the request.body gets messed up.

```
url = "https://whatever/api/v1/dosomething"
data = {"client":{"id":100},"job":{"name":"software developer","field_id":[1,2,3],"level":20}}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

I get a bad request as a result of the code above, and when I check r.request.body:

```
client=id&job=name&job=field_id&job=level
```

I **think** I'm getting a bad request because of the request.body that got parsed in a wrong way, but I am not finding how to parse it correctly.

I already tried to use:

```
req = Request('GET', url, data=data, headers=headers)
prepped = req.prepare()
resp = s.send(prepped)
```

Can someone please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to `json.dumps(data)` when sending json with session.

So it will be

```
r = s.get(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
```

Not

```
r = s.get(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

Comment: I love you. Thanks

Comment: @jaqs, can you accept the answer then?)

Comment: your reply was now accepted =)